# Ubuntu 12.04: HP Photosmart 6515 Only Wired?

Tags: wireless, printing, hp

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I've plugged the HP Photosmart 6515 USB cable and Ubuntu automatically detected it and was able to print/scan through the USB cable.

I connected the printer to the wireless which my laptop is connected to. I try to use the printer wirelessly but it didn't seem to work.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) package from the Ubuntu software center.

Once installed, run it and follow the configuration wizard. Select network printer and choose either autodetect or add printer by IP address (provided you know your printer IP).

[image]

The rest should be straightforward and it will install the driver you need to use it.

[image]

Finally add printer

[image]

After that you should be able to print using wireless.